# wxPython combo.ComboCtrl event handling issue

Tags: wxpython

I have a myComboCtrl (combo.ComboCtrl) object, that I want to react to a change of value in the ComboPopup object I have linked with it - upon click I'd like to update a portion of my frame based on the value that lands in myComboCtrl. So, based on:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/wxpython-users/j6zQC_f12lM

I understand I need to send the event to the ComboCtrl event handler. From what I read, sending events can be done in two ways, either the ProcessEvent method of the EventHandler or by using PostEvent.

So, in my ComboPopup (subclassed from ListCtrl ) I am trying to fire the event

```
def SetStringValue(self, val):
    idx = self.FindItem(-1, val)
    if idx != wx.NOT_FOUND:
        self.Select(idx)
        myComboCtrlEventHandler = self.GetCombo().GetEventHandler()
        myEvent = wx.CommandEvent(0, wx.EVT_COMBOBOX.typeId)
        myComboCtrlEventHandler.ProcessEvent(myEvent)
```

The ComboCtrl is already bound using:

```
    self.myComboCtrl.Bind(wx.EVT_COMBOBOX, self.DoSomethin,None,wxID_MYCOMBOCTRLID)
```

and the DoSomethin function has just a wx.MessageBox inside. When I run the code, clicking the items on the popup correctly fires the SetStringValue, but nothing happens. What am I doing wrong ?

---------------------------------------------------------------- EDIT -----------------------------------------------------------

Here's a sample source file that shows my problem. I expect to get the ComboCtrl to act the same way as the generic ComboBox, alas I cannot get that event thing working

```
import wx
import wx.combo

[wxID_MYFRAME, wxID_MYFRAMECOMBOBOX1, wxID_MYFRAMECOMBOBOX2, wxID_MYFRAMEPANEL1, 
 wxID_MYFRAMESTATICTEXT1, wxID_MYFRAMESTATICTEXT2, 
] = [wx.NewId() for _init_ctrls in range(6)]

######################################################################################

class ListCtrlComboPopup(wx.ListCtrl, wx.combo.ComboPopup):

    def __init__(self):
        self.PostCreate(wx.PreListCtrl())
        wx.combo.ComboPopup.__init__(self)

    def AddItem(self, txt):
        self.InsertStringItem(self.GetItemCount(), txt)

    def OnMotion(self, evt):
        item, flags = self.HitTest(evt.GetPosition())
        if item >= 0:
            self.Select(item)
            self.curitem = item

    def OnLeftDown(self, evt):
        self.value = self.curitem
        self.Dismiss()

    def Init(self):
        self.value = -1
        self.curitem = -1

    def Create(self, parent):
        wx.ListCtrl.Create(self, parent,
                           style=wx.LC_LIST|wx.LC_SINGLE_SEL|wx.SIMPLE_BORDER)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MOTION, self.OnMotion)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.OnLeftDown)
        return True

    def GetControl(self):
        return self

    def SetStringValue(self, val):
        idx = self.FindItem(-1, val)
        if idx != wx.NOT_FOUND:
            self.Select(idx)
            myComboCtrlEventHandler = self.GetCombo().GetEventHandler()
            myEvent = wx.CommandEvent(winid=0, commandType=wx.EVT_COMBOBOX.typeId)
            myComboCtrlEventHandler.ProcessEvent(myEvent)

    def GetStringValue(self):
        if self.value >= 0:
            return self.GetItemText(self.value)
        return ""

    def OnPopup(self):
        wx.combo.ComboPopup.OnPopup(self)

    def OnDismiss(self):
        wx.combo.ComboPopup.OnDismiss(self)

######################################################################################

class myFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, objParent):

        myChoices = ['one','two','three','four']

        wx.Frame.__init__(self, id=wxID_MYFRAME, name='', parent=objParent,
              pos=wx.Point(515, 255), size=wx.Size(258, 129),
              style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE, title='MYFRAME')

        self.panel1 = wx.Panel(id=wxID_MYFRAMEPANEL1, name='panel1', parent=self,
              pos=wx.Point(0, 0), size=wx.Size(250, 102),
              style=wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL)

        self.comboBox1 = wx.ComboBox(choices=myChoices, id=wxID_MYFRAMECOMBOBOX1,
              name='comboBox1', parent=self.panel1, pos=wx.Point(32, 24),
              size=wx.Size(130, 21), style=0, value='comboBox1')

        self.comboBox2 = wx.combo.ComboCtrl(id=wxID_MYFRAMECOMBOBOX2,
              name='comboBox2', parent=self.panel1, pos=wx.Point(32, 56),
              size=wx.Size(130, 21), style=0, value='comboBox2')

        self.staticText1 = wx.StaticText(id=wxID_MYFRAMESTATICTEXT1,
              label='staticText1', name='staticText1', parent=self.panel1,
              pos=wx.Point(176, 24), size=wx.Size(54, 13), style=0)

        self.staticText2 = wx.StaticText(id=wxID_MYFRAMESTATICTEXT2,
              label='staticText2', name='staticText2', parent=self.panel1,
              pos=wx.Point(176, 56), size=wx.Size(54, 13), style=0)

        myComboPopup = ListCtrlComboPopup()
        self.comboBox2.SetPopupControl(myComboPopup)

        for i in range(len(myChoices)):
            print type(myChoices[i])
            myComboPopup.AddItem(myChoices[i])

        self.comboBox1.Bind(wx.EVT_COMBOBOX, self.OnCb1Click,None,wxID_MYFRAMECOMBOBOX1)
        self.comboBox2.Bind(wx.EVT_COMBOBOX, self.OnCb2Click,None,wxID_MYFRAMECOMBOBOX2)

    def OnCb1Click(self, event):
        del self.staticText1
        self.staticText1 = wx.StaticText(id=wxID_MYFRAMESTATICTEXT1,
              label=self.comboBox1.GetValue(), parent=self.panel1,
              pos=wx.Point(176, 24), size=wx.Size(54, 13), style=0)
        event.Skip()

    def OnCb2Click(self, event):
        del self.staticText2
        self.staticText2 = wx.StaticText(id=wxID_MYFRAMESTATICTEXT1,
              label=self.comboBox2.GetValue(), parent=self.panel1,
              pos=wx.Point(176, 24), size=wx.Size(54, 13), style=0)
        event.Skip()

######################################################################################

def main():
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    myFrameObj = myFrame(None)
    myFrameObj.Show()
    app.MainLoop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass in the incorrect parameter while create the event.

It should be:

```
myEvent = wx.CommandEvent(wx.EVT_COMBOBOX.typeId)
```

Here is the source code of the class "CommandEvent":

```
class CommandEvent(Event):
    """
    This event class contains information about command events, which
    originate from a variety of simple controls, as well as menus and
    toolbars.
    """
    thisown = property(lambda x: x.this.own(), lambda x, v: x.this.own(v), doc='The membership flag')
    __repr__ = _swig_repr
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): 
        """
        __init__(self, EventType commandType=wxEVT_NULL, int winid=0) -> CommandEvent

        This event class contains information about command events, which
        originate from a variety of simple controls, as well as menus and
        toolbars.
        """
```

Edit:

It should work, please try this simple demo.

```
    import wx

    def cbEvent(evt):
        print "cbEvent"

    def btnEvent(evt):
        print "btnEvent"
        myComboCtrlEventHandler = cb.GetEventHandler()
        myEvent = wx.CommandEvent(wx.EVT_COMBOBOX.typeId)
        myComboCtrlEventHandler.ProcessEvent(myEvent)


    if __name__=='__main__':
        app = wx.App(redirect=False)
        frame = wx.Frame(None)
        p = wx.Panel(frame)

        cb = wx.ComboBox(p, 500, "default value", (90, 50), (160, -1), "test")
        cb.Bind(wx.EVT_COMBOBOX, cbEvent)

        bt = wx.Button(p, -1, "btn", (90,100))
        bt.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, btnEvent)

        frame.Show()
        app.MainLoop()
```

Edit 2:

When you create the event, you should assign correct ID.
And When you bind the event, you should assign the correct ID as well.

```
myEvent = wx.CommandEvent(winid=self.GetId(), commandType=wx.EVT_COMBOBOX.typeId)
self.comboBox2.Bind(wx.EVT_COMBOBOX, self.OnCb2Click,None,myComboPopup.GetId())
```

Or you can leave them alone(with default wx.ID_ANY):

```
myEvent = wx.CommandEvent(commandType=wx.EVT_COMBOBOX.typeId)
self.comboBox2.Bind(wx.EVT_COMBOBOX, self.OnCb2Click)
```

Both tested with your code :)

Comment: Ok, I've changed that line, but still nothing happens.

Comment: try to bind the event like this: self.myComboCtrl.Bind(wx.EVT_COMBOBOX, self.DoSomethin)

Comment: Yes, the edit you posted will probably work, the thing is you attach events to wx controls, while I am having trouble with the wx.combo control. My events work fine for buttons, listCtrls etc, just the combo.ComboCtrl seems to be doing idk. I have posted a sample code where the event is included, please check that one out :)